# how to share fixed data on facebook if used omniauth for authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, omniauth, facebook-sharer

I have used omniauth for authentication of user in rails. i just want to create a button on my site which when clicked should post to logged in users facebook profile a certain fixed data.
i have tried facebook_share gem but unable to specify the predefine text. kindly help me in this

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In place of facebook_share the better way is to use facebook api. link explains all

https://github.com/aayushkhandelwal11/training-assignment/blob/master/facebookshare.txt